# Rounded corners on a sheet in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've seen the questions on how to round corners of a view in SwiftUI, and I know how to do it. However, how do you increase the cornerRadius value a View that is presented in a .sheet() modifier?

I'm able to do it in UIKit but not in SwiftUI.

What I want to achieve:
[image: rounded corners]

Comment: It's automatically rounded

Comment: sorry. i need to clarify: i wanna increase the cornerRadius value

Comment: @QingwanKuah did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can do it using introspect API with .preferedCornerRadius  However, the documentation does warn that it may break in the future.

Add this to the view being passed to the sheet.

```
Import Introspection

.introspectionViewController { vc in vc.sheetPresentationController?.preferredCornerRadius = 20 }
```

For the record, I decided to build my own custom modals with corner radius, so I can stay purely SwiftUI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).